# How to find the value of 5 variables

Tags: puzzle, cryptarithm

I have an equation:
$$O^R-C+K^Y=ROCKY$$
All of the variables are whole numbers from $0$ to $9$ inclusive. There cannot be any duplicate numbers. I need to find the value of all of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick brute-force Python script reveals
$$9^5-2+6^3=59263$$

Comment: Thanks! (Also thanks for formatting the question and adding tags; I didn't know how to format and what tags to add)

Comment: @RedGuy11 Now please accept my answer.

Comment: Oh yes right I'm new to stackoverflow so I forgot sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let one of the numbers be 0. Then the RHS becomes zero and we can look for 4 other numbers that together satisfy:
$$O^R+K^Y=C$$
And this is quite doable by hand. Starting with the most trivial solutions where one of the remaining numbers is a 1:
$$k^0+n^1=(n+1), n\in\{2, ..., 8\}$$
$$k^0+1^n=2$$

Any integer power greater than $2^3$ and $3^2$ will exceed the allowed range for $C$, but we can still toy around with these two:
$$k^0+2^3=9, k\in\{1,4,5,6,7,8\}$$
$$0^k+2^3=8, k\in\{1,4,5,6,7,9\}$$
$$0^k+3^2=9, k\in\{1,4,5,6,7,8\}$$

Comment: What do you consider a "full answer"? I've given a total of 88 possible combinations for all variables.